# How to transform image to show the pressure exerted by touch?

Tags: android, algorithm, image-processing, 3d

Lets say I have an android application that shows an image of a pillow. When someone touches the image and presses the screen, I want the image to be transformed to show the effect of the pressure. e.g. If someone presses the image of the pillow, a depression should appear in the image at the point of touch as if it has been pressed in real.

I have searched the web for pointers on how to do that but could not find any. Are there any image transformation algorithms that can simulate something soft being pressed?

Any pointers to code, libraries or research papers would be great.

I don't want it to be absolutely perfect. Any good enough algorithm would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad for not looking into the API demos. There is a sample in the android sdk (BitmapMesh) which does a similar thing and is so simple to implement. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 2):

i found this java library that seems to have a lot of in built image processing filters

http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html

it might help i think warpfilter is the one you are looking for

Comment: Thanks. Apparently warp filter serves the purpose. Let me try that out.

Comment: Unfortunately the filters require java.awt.* so they would not work on android. I will have to rework most of the source code.

Comment: i ran into the same problem a little while ago when i needed to evaluate javascript on android, there is no javax.script in android

Answer (score 2):

You have several approach, but it is essentially an artistic problem.

**The cheap way**
I would have an animation going from "no pressure" to "strongest pressure" with transparent background. Then I would put the animation on top of the pillow picture, mapping the pressure value to the corresponding frame in the animation. You can also have an animation for the whole pillow, and let the user push it only at the center.

**The scientific way**
you can simulate the pillow with a finite elements model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method), render it with a 3d modelisation tool like blender, and somehow integrate the result in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I would prefer to try the scientific method, though it seems complex.

Comment: there is a video which seems to cover the topic of simulation using maya: http://www.lugher3d.com/tutorials-for-maya/video-tutorial-how-modelling-bed-pillow-with-ncloth. Using the results in your application is another problem. I have not checked the video since an account is required to download it.

Answer (score 1):

You know i was thinking about what effect you are trying to create and the best way to achieve the effect might not be to distort the image in real time. 
first of all your app will become very expensive (to battery and memory), it might not be able to perform satisfactorily on lower end android phones. 
also, even producing an average realistic effect yourself could involve a lot of trial and error.

A better way to do it would be to create 10-25 frames of the animation effect you want to display, you could easily achieve this with photoshop (liquify tool) or gimp (ok may be not so easily if you have never used these),

once you have the frames, just change the frames as pressure applied by user changes

Answer (score 0):

Can't exactly write the code for you, but there's a method called [getPressure()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure%28int%29)  in MotionEvent that can give you the variable you need to figure out how to transform your image.  Though I'd bet its pretty unreliable and probably varies from device-to-device.